# SQL Toad/Oracle strange behavior

Tags: oracle, toad, ora-00900, ora-00923

I have just installed Toad for Oracle and it has a strange behavior.

[This works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOjyr.png)

```
select 
*
from 
dd_contract
```

[And this does not, generates errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sH1Pa.png)

```
select 
*

from 
dd_contract
```

It is either a FROM not found, or a Invalid statement error. The only difference is that there is and empty line between the last column and the FROM keyword. It is probably some setting somewhere, but I do not even know how to search for it.

Answer (score 5):

Uncheck the "Treat blank line as statement terminator" option on the Execute/Compile page in Options.

You can use Ctrl+Enter to execute code in Toad, that logic uses blank lines as statement terminators.

Comment: @laszlo Please mark this answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark.  This will help future searchers by indicating what worked for you.